# c program need to find mistake?

Tags: c

I don't know where is mistake. help me to find it :)
Need to find same 3 natural numbers a,b,c which would be an arithmetic progression and a*a - b*b - c*c= dddd. d= any number. for example 53, 37,21. 53*53 - 37*37 -21*21=999.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    int i,j,k,l,a,b,c;
    
    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        for (j = 1; i < 100; i++)
            for (k = 1; i < 100; i++)
                if ((i - j) == (j - k)) {
                    a = i;
                    b = j;
                    c = k;
                    for (l = 1; l < 10; i++) {
                        if ((a*a-b*b-c*c) == (111*l)) {
                            printf("these numbers are: %d %d %d \n",a, b, c);
                        }
                    }
                }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should fix your indentation.

Comment: Always provide correctly indented code. This time I fixed it for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Posting several lines of code and saying "What is my mistake?" won't quite work. You need to clearly describe the problem you're trying to solve, explain *how* the code isn't working, and ask a specific question we can answer. Please [edit] to add that information so we can try to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your for loops over j and k are incorrect: i<100; i++ should be j<100; j++ and similar for k. The loop over l also wrongly increments i instead of l.

Fixing those problems gives me:

```
these numbers are: 28 15 2 
these numbers are: 43 27 11 
these numbers are: 47 37 27 
these numbers are: 50 37 24 
these numbers are: 53 37 21 
these numbers are: 94 74 54
```

which seems to be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment the j, k and l variables in their for loops instead of incrementing i in each loop.